# Regex to find exact length with variable characters in a XML

Tags: xml, regex

Is there a way to find variable fixed length characters between specified tags in a XML like below

```
<Event id="2965652b-f7b7-4539-abb6-33cae0fca2d1" name="updateInfo" eventType="updateInfo">
    <eventTime>2014-11-11T06:35:22Z</eventTime>
    <eventAttributes>
      <EventAttribute>
        <name>userId</name>
        <value>9376BDA4-A187-4CFF-8A49-482A4FD514F4</value>
      </EventAttribute>
    </eventAttributes>
  </Event>
<Event id="4909eb79-f807-42f5-8281-27485ee68956" name="login" eventType="login">
    <eventTime>2014-11-11T06:35:21Z</eventTime>
    <eventAttributes>
      <EventAttribute>
        <name>userId</name>
        <value>9376BDA4-A187-4CFF-8A49-482A4FD514F4</value>
      </EventAttribute>
    </eventAttributes>
  </Event>
```

I tried below with  [1]: http://www.regexr.com/   but no luck

```
<Event id="2965652b-f7b7-4539-abb6-33cae0fca2d1" name="updateInfo" eventType="updateInfo"><eventTime>.{20}<\/eventTime><e...
```

I wanted to verify whether following text is there in the XML. Since `2014-11-11T06:35:22Z` is a variable thought of adding Regex there

```
<Event id="2965652b-f7b7-4539-abb6-33cae0fca2d1" name="updateInfo" eventType="updateInfo">
        <eventTime>2014-11-11T06:35:22Z</eventTime>
        <eventAttributes>
          <EventAttribute>
            <name>userId</name>
            <value>9376BDA4-A187-4CFF-8A49-482A4FD514F4</value>
          </EventAttribute>
        </eventAttributes>
      </Event>
```

Finally I pass this search text in to grep command and trying to extract XML file name out of a folder and then use `records = new XmlParser().parseText(eventFile)` in groovy code to validate elements.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What environment/language are you working with? What should be returned? Why use regex for this? What's the purpose of doing it?

Comment: Please provide an example of your expected output as well as a justification of why you're trying to parse xml with regex instead of a dedicated parser.

Comment: What are variable fixed length characters? Do you mean the length is fixed but the characters are variable?

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes, correct. Looks like `.{20} ` is not working in `grep `. `.* ` is working though. In my case I can't use `.* ` because there could be same type of events consecutively which result incorrect results. So need to give the character length in Regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't account for the newlines and spaces in front of the `<eventTime>` tag.  Put a `\s*` between the `><`s and you'll get it.  Ie.

```
<Event id="2965652b-f7b7-4539-abb6-33cae0fca2d1" name="updateInfo" eventType="updateInfo">\s*<eventTime>.{20}<\/eventTime>
```

Not that this is very robust or negates what others are saying about using a proper XML parser (which is the best idea).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried suggested solution in ` http://www.regexr.com/ ` but couldn't see any matching string. Should I add `\s* ` for each newline?

Comment: I don't understand, here's the regexr of precisely the block of text in your post, and precisely my line as a regex: http://regexr.com/39std

Comment: ...but also, yes, anywhere that there's a newline or other whitespace you'll need a `\s*`

Comment: Yes you are correct. After adding `\s* ` in every line in my search text, it worked in `http://www.regexr.com/ `. If I include this in the grep command should I do that? Because in `grep ` doesn't that consider XML as one string?

Comment: `grep` uses a different regex syntax by default, you'll need to use `egrep` or `grep -E` so that `\s` works.

Comment: YES you nailed it. I was using `grep H ` before which causing the problem. `grep E ` is working well for me.